# Why (finite) Blaschke products are actually rational fractions?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, blaschke-products

I have found in several books the following affirmation :

Let $f: \Delta \rightarrow \Delta$ be a non constant holomorphic function that extends continuously to $\overline{\Delta}$, $\Delta$ being the open unit disk. Then $f$ is a finite Blaschke product, i.e. of the form
$$B(z) = e^{i \theta} \prod_{k=1}^d \frac{z- a_i}{1-\overline{a_i} z}$$

Now it is not hard to check that those rational fractions do indeed send $\Delta$ onto $\Delta$, but I do not know where to find a proof that they are the only ones.

Where can I find that proof in the literature ? I am not interested in the infinite product case, only finite. 
(Of course, if anyone is kind enough to post a proof, that would do fine as well =)

Comment: You need to multiply with a constant of modulus 1 as well.

Comment: yup, i'll edit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to assume that $f$ is non constant and that $f$ maps the unit circle into itself. In this case, the result follows by the maximum modulus principle.

Indeed, first note that $f$ has a finite number of zeros in $\mathbb{D}$, otherwise since $f$ is not identically zero the zeros would accumulate on the circle, which contradicts the fact that $|f|=1$ there.

Then, consider $B$ a finite blaschke product that has exactly the same zeros than $f$. Then $B/f$ and $f/B$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$, continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Furthermor, $|B/f|=1$ and $|f/B|=1$ on the unit circle. By the maximum modulus principle, we get that $|B/f| \equiv 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$ and thus $B/f$ is a unimodular constant. This gives the result.

Note that infinite blaschke products do not extend continuously to the unit circle : they have (essential) singularities where the zeros accumulate.

Comment: thanks ! I suspected there was an easy proof since nobody seemed to bother mentionning it, but I didn't think of it !

Comment: Nit: zeros can't accumulate at a pole. You get essential singularities.

Comment: You're right, I meant singularities. I'll edit the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The result can be found in section 6.12 (p. 197) of the encyclopedic *An introduction to classical complex analysis*, vol 1, by Robert B. Burckel. In case you like to go to original sources, the author cites Fatou, “Sur les fonctions holomorphes et bornées à l'intérieur d'un cercle”, *Bull. Soc. Math. France* 51 (1923), 191–202.